# "\b" is added to the string as a character

Tags: c++

In the below code the "\b" removes a char from the string, but it increases its size as if the char could be inside it but not visible.

```
while (true) {
c = _getch();
if (c=='\r') {break;} 
else if (c=='\b') { cout<<"\b"<<" "<<"\b"; s+="\b \b"; }
else {cout<<"*"; s=s+c;}
}
```

For instance the the size of this string (abc"\b"d), "c is removed and replaced by d", is still 5.

I would like to know how to efficiently handle the backspace in this circumstance.

Comment: Backspace character is still a character.

Comment: That is exactly what should happen. You need to **remove** the last character of s upon encountering a backspace; there's no other way.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric, that is absolutely right but I how could I fully get rid of it ?

Comment: But where is your string in the question?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: String is captured in the while loop.

Comment: @FirstLast Sorry, I didn't see it.

Comment: Why are you reading it in character by character instead of using `std::cin >> s` or `std::getline(std::cin, s)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading character by character into a string, you could do something like this:

```
std::string mystr;
while (true) {
    c = _getch();
    if (c=='\r') {break;} 

    if(c == '\b')
    {
        // This will remove last character from your string
        if(mystr.size () > 0)
        {
              cout<<"\b"<<" "<<"\b";
              mystr.resize (mystr.size () - 1); 
              // or mystr.pop_back() in C++11
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"*";
        mystr += c;

    }    
}
```

Comment: ...why is no one upvoting this answer? :-?

Comment: Apparently, they want me to earn the unsung hero badge :).

Comment: Could it be that `_getch()` is a platform or compiler specific function and you haven't told us which platform or compiler it is used with?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Because OP is echoing `*` by himself to the stdout, I guess, he is using this implementation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak(v=vs.90).aspx: `The _getch and_getwch functions read a single character from the console without echoing the character`

Answer (score 2):

You need to "physically" remove the last character from the string when you get a backspace:

```
while (true) {
    c = _getch();
    if (c=='\r') {
        break;
    }
    if (c=='\b') {
        cout<<"\b"<<" "<<"\b";
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
        }
    }
    else {cout<<"*"; s=s+c;}
}
```

As an optimization, we can trim `s` instead of reassigning, as suggested by Jason:

```
    s.resize(s.size() -1);
```

(While we're at it, we could save `s.length()` (or `s.size()`) into a local variable to avoid the extra call - assuming the compiler, knowing about std::string, doesn't do it already).

Comment: I'd rather do s.erase(s.end() -1) or s.resize(s.size() -1) instead of using substring to avoid the extra copy

Comment: Indeed, you're right. But on the other hand, *this* cycle is heavily *user*-bound. Keys from a keyboard aren't likely to be coming through at more than perhaps one every 10ms ("tap and hold the backspace key"). I'll update the answer though.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that I have to -1 the length of string.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(char c=_getch(); c!='\r'; c=_getch())
  if(c=='\b')
    mystr.pop_back();
  else
    mystr.push_back(c);
```